# EF Core helper method for explicit loading references and collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, lambda, entity-framework-core

EF Core has support for [explicit loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading). The context has two overloads, one for references and one for collections.

Having two methods is not useful, and gets messy. I want a single method for accepting both as a params array.

So instead of this

```
await context.Entry(customer).Collection(e => e.Orders).LoadAsync();
await context.Entry(customer).Collection(e => e.Returns).LoadAsync();
await context.Entry(customer).Reference(e => e.Account).LoadAsync();
```

I want to do this:

```
await context.Entry(customer).Load(e=>e.Orders, e=>e.Returns, e=>e.Account);
```

I assume this is possible, because there is something similar with `context.Include(...)` which accepts both collections and references.

In my context class, I have this so far:

```
public async Task Load<TEntity>(TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] propertyExpressions)
  where TEntity : class
{

  foreach (var propertyExpression in propertyExpressions) {

    var isCollection = typeof(IEnumerable).GetTypeInfo()
                       .IsAssignableFrom(propertyExpression.Body.Type);

    if(isCollection)
    {
      await Entry(entity)
        .Collection(propertyExpression)     // problem is here !!!!!
        .LoadAsync();
    }
    else
    {
      await Entry(entity)
        .Reference(propertyExpression)
        .LoadAsync();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem line is shown above. The input is `object` but `.Collection()` expects `IEnumerable<TProperty>`.

How do I make this work?

Comment: You could use the string overload of `Collection()` and pass the property expression's property name.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah I saw that overload... though I'd like to get it working without magic strings, if possible. I'm using that approach until I can get this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking into account that both methods return [`NavigationEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.navigationentry) derived class, and both use `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ExpressionExtensions.GetPropertyAccess` method to get the `PropertyInfo.Name` from the passed lambda expression, you can use the same approach to retrieve the name and then use the [`Navigation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_EntityEntry_Navigation_System_String_) method:

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;

```
public async Task Load<TEntity>(TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] propertyExpressions)
    where TEntity : class
{
    foreach (var propertyExpression in propertyExpressions)
    {
        var propertyName = propertyExpression.GetPropertyAccess().Name;
        await Entry(entity).Navigation(propertyName).LoadAsync();
    }
}
```